# Problem with Creation form (Simpleform) PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, simple-form

Hello i have an issue with my app Rails when i try to create an "Enfant" who belongs to an user and a Nounou but my problem is when i create an "enfant" i'm a user with an ID but, I haven't chosen yet a nounou so i haven't got a nounou_id this is my differents code(i try to put optional: true but it doesn't work : 
Models and Schema

```
class Enfant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :nounou, optional: true
end


class Nounou < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enfants
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :enfants
end


  create_table "enfants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.bigint "nounou_id", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["nounou_id"], name: "index_enfants_on_nounou_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_enfants_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "nounous", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "price"
    t.string "localisation"
    t.integer "evaluation"
    t.integer "places"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "photo"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.string "photo"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Comment: your controller accept/permit all params that you need?

Comment: Yes i create a method :   `def enfant_params
    params.require(:enfant).permit(:last_name, :first_name, :user_id)
  end` but i try with nounou_id and not that dosen't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the `null: false` option:

- It doesn't consider that the `belongs_to` association could be optional.
- If there are already records in the database, running the migration will generate an Exception, as there is not a default value (in PostgreSQL, `PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: column "user_id" contains null values`).

[Here's the reference.](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37858)

**Solution:**

- Your form probably is sending `nounou_id` as `nil` or something. You need to verify that by inspecting your `params` reaching your `create` method.
- You have made `nounou_id` optional in model only but you need to run a migration to make it optional in db too where it clearly says it can't be false (`null: false`).
  You can take help for that migration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59396128/10313894).
- You should modify your `enfant_params` method in rails:

```
def enfant_params
  params.require(:enfant).permit(:last_name, :first_name, :user_id, :nounou_id)
end
```

I am confident that this will solve your issue but if you still need help, update your question with your form code, `create` action and `enfant_params` and updated `schema`.

**Good Luck.**

Comment: @AlexandreViretti editing a migration that has already been run is no use and destructive even. You should create a new migration to make it optional again with the link I provided and can you please accept the answer and upvote? Thanks

Comment: Thanks it works with solution i posted with your solution

Comment: no no. you should not edit your schema directly without migration especially if you are a new developer. This will cause issues if you want to replicate your project. Follow migrations way.

Comment: no i do a new migration `class ChangeColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    change_column :enfants, :nounou_id, :bigint, null:true
  end
end
`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem when attempting to add a user_id column to a cats table. It kept returning the same NotNullViolation Error. This worked for me, to clear the error so that I was able to keep the "null: false" constraint on the column added to the table. Most likely I am running into the error because there are already cats without users. Run the below commands and it should fix the error for you as well. I learned about this trick from this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487954/rails-alter-migrations-during-early-development-phases#_=_).

```
rails db:drop
rails db:create
rails db:migrate --trace
```

Comment: Don't know why this didn't get upvoted.  Worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot it was in my migration file : `t.bigint "nounou_id"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false` 
 I delete null:false for nounou_id and it works ;)

Comment: This will cause issues if you ever create db again or copy or destroy. all manual changes will be lost. migrations are made specifically for this reason: to keep your database architecture changes recorded.

Answer (score 0):

If there are already records in the database you can provide a default value in the migration like:

```
add_reference :table_name, :association, null: false, foreign_key: true, default: default_value
```